# animating elements in firefox moves other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am developing single page website with keyboard controlled scrolling.

I have created javascript function that animates divs to create scroll effect.

js:

```
var current_page = "#first";
function animateScroll(curr, des){
    $(des).show();
    $(des).css("position", "absolute");
    $(des).css("z-index", "2");
    $(curr).css("z-index", "1");
    $(des).css("top", "100%");
    $(des).animate({
        top : "0px"
    }, 800, function(){
        $(curr).hide();
        current_page = des;
    });
}
$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 40){
        animateScroll(current_page, "#" + $(current_page).next().attr("id"));
    }
});
```

html :

```
<div id = 'why_am_i_moving'></div>
<div class = 'main' id = 'first'>press down key</div>
<div class = 'main' id = 'second'></div>
<div class = 'main' id = 'third'></div>
<div class = 'main' id = 'fourth'></div>
<div class = 'main' id = 'fifth'></div>
```

css :

```
body, html{
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
}
div.main{
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    display : none;
    background : white;
}
#first{
    background : red;
    display : block;
}
#second{
    background : blue;
}
#third{
    background : green;
}
#fourth{
    background : yellow;
}
#why_am_i_moving{
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    background : brown;
    z-index : 3;
}
```

Sometimes when I run my function on keyup all my elements on page move up slightly before starting animation.

This only happens in firefox(38.0.5) and only if I use down key to initiate animation.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bd8wzr1L/2/

Does someone know what is happening here ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is a bug in Firefox. The body is moving up when you press down. You can fix this by adding `position: absolute;` to the body tag.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd8wzr1L/4/)